# How to add required listeners for testPlan or thread group in jmeter api using java?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have created the Jmeter script from Apache Jmeter API. But, not able to understand how to add required listeners  for testPlan or thread group in jmeter api using java?

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't. Listeners are useful when you develop or debug your test, when it comes to test execution all you need to do is to generate a .jtl results file.

Listeners don't add any value, when you run your load test in non-GUI mode (i.e. from Java code) they just create resource overhead in terms of memory usage and increased disk IO. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) article for more details.

So instead of adding listeners just amend your Java code to add storing JMeter test results into a .jtl file and once your test finishes you will be able to open this .jtl results file with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it.

If you are uncertain regarding how to generate a .jtl results file from Java code here is a snippet:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}


String logFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl"
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

If you need to amend result file configuration to store some extra data or don't store metrics you don't want - you can do it via [relevant JMeter Properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: Very useful answer. It's clear that adding listeners it's kind of a application killer in terms of performance but is that the only way to get your results? I mean, what if I wanted to investigate the results at the end of the test? Is the only available way saving the jtl file just to open it again and parse it (with all the problems that this brings...). I couldn't see any obvious way of collecting the results from any of the *Result* classes in the API.

Comment: This solution does not work if your are doing distributed load test from the code i.e results are not saved in the jtl file if the test is run on remote hosts (1 master and 2 slaves each on different machine)